# Show that MA$(m)$ process constructed from an i.i.d. sequence is $m$-dependent

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, independence, time-series

Consider the definition of $m$-dependence:

> A sequence of random variables ${(X_t)}_{t \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is said to be $m$-dependent for $m \in \mathbb{N}_{0}$ if for each $t$ ${(X_s)}_{s \leq t}$ is independent of ${(X_s)}_{s \geq t+m+1}$.

Now let ${(Z_t)}_{t \in \mathbb{Z}}$ be an i.i.d. sequence of random variables, and define $$X_t := Z_t+\theta_1 Z_{t-1} + \ldots + \theta_m Z_{t-m}$$ with $\theta_1, \ldots, \theta_q \in \mathbb{R}$.

> How can one show that ${(X_t)}_{t \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is $m$-dependent?

My reasoning:

Consider $X_r$ and $X_s$ with $r -s\geq m+1$. Then

$$
X_r = Z_r+\theta_1 Z_{r-1} + \ldots + \theta_r Z_{r-m},
$$
$$
X_s = Z_s+\theta_1 Z_{s-1} + \ldots + \theta_s Z_{s-m}.
$$
Since $\sigma(Z_s, \ldots, Z_{s-m}) \perp \sigma(Z_r, \ldots, Z_{r-m})$, then $X_r$ and $X_s$ are also independent whenever $r -s\geq m+1$.

But how can one show that for every $t \in Z$ it holds
$$
\sigma({(X_s)}_{s \leq t}) \perp \sigma({(X_s)}_{s \geq m + t +1})\ ?$$

Comment: Your question is probably "How can one show that ${(X_t)}_{t \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is $m$-dependent?", rather than "How can one show that ${(Z_t)}_{t \in T}$ is $m$-dependent?" (thus, $X$ instead of $Z$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ instead of $T$). To answer this, simply show that, for every $t$ in $\mathbb{Z}$, $$
\sigma({(X_s)}_{s \leq t})\subseteq\sigma({(Z_s)}_{s \leq t})$$ and $$ \sigma({(X_s)}_{s \geq m + t +1})\subseteq\sigma({(Z_s)}_{s \geq t+1})$$ and conclude.

Comment: That now leads me to the question which I posted here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2408796/is-it-true-that-sigmax-t-t-leq-r-perp-perp-sigmax-t-t

Comment: Ha. Then I find frankly problematic that you asked the present question, if the result the other question asks about, which is one or two levels more basic, is not clear to you... IOW, which kind of answer do you expect here if the result over there is not taken for granted / well understood / considered as obvious / whatever?

Comment: I had posted this much earlier

Comment: Indeed. Exactly the problem I underline.

Comment: I posted the question and later realized the problem is narrowed down to the one you mentioned. Then posted the second question.
Does this clarify the  problem?