# Let ${(X_t)}_{t \in Z}$ be an independent sequence. Show that $ \sigma({(X_t)}_{t \leq r}) \perp\!\!\!\perp \sigma({(X_t)}_{t \geq s}). $

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, independence

> In relation to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2407984/), let ${(X_t)}_{t \in Z}$ be an independent sequence. I am trying to show that for $r < s$
>   $$
> \sigma({(X_t)}_{t \leq r}) \perp\!\!\!\perp \sigma({(X_t)}_{t \geq s}).
> $$

My reasoning:

Let $I = \{i_1, \ldots, i_n\}$ and $J_2 = \{j_1. \ldots, j_m\}$ be two finite ordered index sets with $i_n \leq r < s \leq j_1$.

To  show that 
$$
\sigma{(X_t)}_{t \in I} \perp\!\!\perp \sigma{(X_t)}_{t \in J}
$$ 
define two families

$$
\mathcal{F}_1 = \{ A_1 \cap\ldots\cap A_n: A_k \in \sigma(X_{i_k}), k = 1 \ldots n \},
$$

$$
\mathcal{F}_2 = \{ B_1 \cap\ldots\cap B_m: B_k \in \sigma(X_{j_k}), k = 1 \ldots m \}.
$$

It can be shown that both $\mathcal{F}_1$ and $\mathcal{F}_2$ are $\cap$-stable generators of $\sigma{(X_t)}_{t \in I}$ and $\sigma{(X_t)}_{t \in J}$ respectively. Moreover $\mathcal{F}_1$ and $\mathcal{F}_2$ are independent, i.e. $\forall A \in \mathcal{F}_1$ and $\forall B \in \mathcal{F}_2$ it holds
$$
P(A \cap B) = P(A_1 \cap\ldots\cap A_n \cap B_1 \cap\ldots\cap B_m) = P(A_1)\dots P(A_n)P(B_1) \dots P(B_m) = P(A_1 \cap \ldots A_n)P(B_1 \cap \ldots \cap B_m) = P(A)P(B).
$$
Therefore $\sigma{(X_t)}_{t \in I} \perp\!\!\perp \sigma{(X_t)}_{t \in J}$.

Now, I want to show this for the general case stated above. I could further define

$$
\mathcal{F}_1 = \left\{ \bigcap_{t \leq r}A_t: A_t \in \sigma(X_t)\right\},
$$

$$
\mathcal{F}_2 = \left\{ \bigcap_{t \geq s}A_t: A_t \in \sigma(X_t)\right\}.
$$

And again $\mathcal{F}_1$ and $\mathcal{F}_2$ are $\cap$-stable generators for $\sigma({(X_t)}_{t \leq r})$ and $\sigma({(X_t)}_{t \geq s})$. But from here I cannot use the same argument as for the finite index sets, since independence is defined in terms of finitely many events and not countably many.

> So how can one show this? Maybe there is a much easier argument that I am missing?

Comment: Why a downvote? The question is asked very well.

Comment: In your chain of equalities, the last $ = P(A_1\cap \dots\cap A_n)P(B_1\cap\dots \cap B_n)$ is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I could further define ...  again $\mathcal F_1$ and $\mathcal F_2$ are $\cap$-stable generators  for $\sigma({(X_t)}_{t \leq r})$ and $\sigma({(X_t)}_{t \geq s})$

No, that's not right; the intersections you write even need not to be measurable.

Suitable generators for those $\sigma$-algebras are 
$$
\mathcal{F}_1 = \big\{ A_1 \cap\ldots\cap A_n: n\ge 1; t_1,\dots,t_n\le r; A_k \in \sigma(X_{t_k}), k = 1,  \ldots, n\big\}
$$
and 
$$
\mathcal{F}_2 = \big\{ B_1 \cap\ldots\cap B_m: m\ge 1; t_1,\dots,t_m\ge s; B_j \in \sigma(X_{t_j}), j = 1,  \ldots, m\big\}.
$$
Using them, you can repeat your argument. And I doubt there is anything simpler than that.

Comment: I think we do not have a problem with measurability, since the intersection involves only countably many sets, i.e. the index set of the stochastic process is $\mathbb{Z}$. However, it still does not seem to be helpful for the problem. I also think that the families you defined can be used to show the same result in the case when the index set is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yes,  I thought your index set is $\mathbb R$. This does not matter anyway; the argument works for any index set. So why do you think it's not helpful?

Comment: I mean the families which I had defined cause no problem in terms of measurability, yet seem to be unhelpful for the problem. Your argument works fine.