# Variance of sum of $m$ dependent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, variance, central-limit-theorem

Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be a sequence of identically distributed and $m$-dependent random variables with $\mathbb{E}[X_i]=0$, $0<Var(X_i)<\infty$ ($m$-dependent means that each $X_i$ is independent of $X_{i+j}$ for $|i-j|\ge m $.

Suppose $Y$ is a random variable with $\mathbb{E}[Y]=0$ and $Var(Y)<\infty$.

Assume also that $Y$ is independent of $X_m,X_{m+1},...$

We know that
$$ \frac{Y+\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i}{\sqrt{n}}\overset{d}{\longrightarrow} N(0,\sigma^2) $$

from the Hoeffding-Robbins theorem, but I am struggling to show that $\sigma^2>0 $ even though intuitively it seems true.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that you correctly defined $m$-dependency? Look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2407984/show-that-mam-process-constructed-from-an-i-i-d-sequence-is-m-dependent. Shouldn't it be $|j|>m$?